# AWS Lambda: access the invocation parameters from error handler

Tags: error-handling, parameters, invoke, aws-lambda

Using AWS Lambda, how can I get the invocation parameters that the lambda was called with, inside the lambda error handling? i.e.:

```
lambda.invoke(lambda_params, function(err, obj) {
    if(err){
        // how do I access lambda_params from here?
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _invocation parameters_?

Comment: +1 for birnbaum, your problem is a bit unclear to me as well. Basically, if you want to access the parameters passed when triggering the lambda, then you have access as you are the one invoking the lambda (you did   value the lambda_params context); and if you want the data returned by the lambda function then use the "data" parameter of your callback.

Comment: @birnbaum, I mean exactly what the question embedded in the code says which is how to access the "lambda_params" variable. I can understand your confusion, however, given that it is a stupid question. Tom, thanks for the answer. I didn't realize the function inherits variables that can be accessed with the same syntax as local vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're really asking is irrelevant to AWS Lambda, if I am understanding correctly, you want to access a variable called 'lambda_params' within the scope of the callback function. If so, then this is a question aimed towards how to access variables within the scope of a callback function in the specific language you're talking about.

Am not sure which language you're referring to in the above code but I believe you should be able to access `lambda_params` directly within the scope of the function

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right. The example was in Node. I was thrown off by the JSON stringification that was being done on the payload of the lambda_params, which required JSON.parse to get the payload back, and mistakenly thought that the problem was that the lambda_params variable was not accessible.

Comment: @mwag Glad I was helpful